# Writing LaTeX in JSON file

Tags: json, latex

How would I include the math symbol Pi in a JSON file? \p seems to be reserved in JSON.

```
{
    "Text": "This is the symbol for the number Pi: $\pi$",
    "Type": "A"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash `"This is the symbol for the number Pi: $\\pi$"`. Otherwise, the string literal tries to interpret `\p` in the same way that it would interpret something like `\n`.

Comment: So my LaTeX parser will interpret this as `$\pi$`?

Comment: Yes.  The JSON parser reads the literal string `"\\pi"` as the string object containing `"\pi"`.  You can play with the input box in https://jsfiddle.net/nugxcxr8/1/ to see how the JSON parser is going to react to various strings.